# Supress logging of error with express middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to suppress the logging of the error in the console when handling it with express middleware.
Since I already log the error through the use of my own (preferred) logger I have no use of the regular log.

Is this even possible, and if so how?

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()
const server = app.listen(3000, () => { console.log(`Server running at port ${server.address().port}`) })

app.get('/error', (req, res) => {
    throw new Error('Oops, something went wrong!')
})

const handleError = (error, req, res, next) => {
    if (error) {
        // Suppose we would use a logger below to log the error properly in our console
        // For the example I left it commented out since its not relevant
        // logger.info(`${error.stack}`)
        res.status(500).send(`${error.message}`)
    }
    next(error)
}
app.use(handleError)
```

Comment: Don't call `next(error)`

Comment: @Keith that fixed it, thanks.